# Jemand as adjective? Declension after determine?

Tags: indefinite-pronoun

In `canoo.net` I had read that:

> When (irgend)jemand and niemand are followed by a nominalized adjective, the neuter singular adjective form ending in –es can be used for all cases:

```
Jemand/Niemand Unbekanntes kam herein.
```

My questions:

1. In this sentence: "Jemand Unbekanntes", *Unbekanntes* is an adjectival noun. What is the role of *Jemand*? Is it an adjective? A pronoun?
2. Can we use *jemand* as an adjective, like "jemand Mann"?
3. If *jemand* comes after the determiner, how is it declined? Example: "Solch ein Jemand ist unserer Beobachtung wert". Is it declined like an adjective?

Comment: The answer for 2. is definitely **no**.

Comment: Could the question-closers tell the OP, where does the needed information appear in the "dictionary, thesaurus, or conjugation table" ? To me, this is a completely valid (and interesting) question. Wrong assumptions don't turn a post into a bad question.

Comment: @c.p. In jedem der folgenden Beispiellinks liest man sofort nach, dass _jemand_ ein Indefinitpronomen ist: https://www.dwds.de/wb/jemand; https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/jemand; https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/jemand; oder auf der vom OP favorisierten Plattform: http://www.canoo.net/services/Controller?input=jemand&MenuId=Search&service=canooNet&lang=de

Comment: Thanks for response, I know it is an indefinite pronoun, but some indefinite pronouns can also be adjective or noun or article and some can not, that is why I gave examples in sentences

Comment: @orodeous: _"... some indefinite pronouns can also be adjective or noun or article ..."_ Can you give examples of indefinite pronouns that are also adjectives? I would be surprised if there were any.

Answer (score 2):

Answers:

> In this sentence: *Jemand Unbekanntes*, *Unbekanntes* is an adjectival noun. What is the role of *jemand*? Is it an adjective? A pronoun?

Any grammar will tell you that *jemand* (and *niemand*) are **indefinite pronouns**. So, no adjective. Definitely not. (BTW: I don't like your term of an *adjectival noun* - Rather call it a *substantivized adjective*, because that is what it is.)

> Can we use jemand as an adjective? like "jemand Mann"?

Also definitely not. You cannot use pronouns as adjectives.

> If jemand comes after the determiner, how is it declined? Example: "solch ein Jemand ist unserer Beobachtung wert". Is it declined like an adjective?

*Solch ein jemand* is a grammatical oxymoron and just about as wrong as "such an anyone". You cannot address a **specific** *anyone*. This would be possible with the **Substantive** "Niemand" (yes, the other indefinite pronoun has a substantivated counterpart, also like in English) such as in

> Komm' mir bloß nicht auf die Idee, so einen Niemand zu heiraten.

Meaning a person of no relevance. This does not apply to *jemand*, though.

And yes, in other situations, the indefinite pronouns niemand/jemand are declined, just like any other pronoun (but not like adjectives):

> (N)Jemand muss das Geschirr abwaschen.
>
> (G)Er wollte nicht jemandes Diener sein.
>
> (D)Die Hausaufgaben habe ich bei jemandem in der Schule abgeschrieben.
>
> (A)Ich muss heute abend noch dringend jemand(en) treffen.

But they are normally **not** declined if they come with a substantivized adjective that carries the declension (so it's either the pronoun that is declined or the substantivated adjective, but normally not both)

> (G)Er wollte nicht jemand Unbekanntes Diener sein / jemandes Unbekannten (This is pretty uncommon)
>
> (D)Die Hausaufgaben habe ich bei jemand Fleißigem abgeschrieben./ bei jemandem Fleißigen
>
> (A)Ich muss jemand Reichen treffen. / jemanden Reichen

Comment: I <3 your example sentence (D) :-D ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Absolutely no pun intended. And I always tell the truth. And the Earth is a disk.

Comment: _"And the Earth is a disk."_ LOL!

Comment: „Solch ein Jemand“ ist grammatikalisch schon ok. Nur den Text, für den das die richtige Stillebene ist, müsste man halt finden.

Comment: @idmean Zumindest der Duden führt einen substantivischen Gebrauch nicht auf. Ich glaube auch nicht, dass es hier ein grammatikalisches, sondern eher ein logisches Problem gibt.

Comment: *Jemand sollte das tun. – Und genau diesen Jemand suche ich gerade.*